# How to run a pytest test for each item in a list of arguments

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Suppose I have a list of HTTP URLs like

```
endpoints = ["e_1", "e_2", ..., "e_n"]
```

And I want to run `n` tests, one for each endpoint. How can I do that?

A simple way to test all the endpoints at once would be

```
def test_urls():
    for e in endpoints:
        r = get(e)
        assert r.status_code < 400
```

or something like that. But as you can see, this is one test for all the `n` endpoints and I would like a little more granularity than that.

I have tried using a fixture like

```
@fixture
def endpoint():
    for e in endpoints:
        yield e
```

but, apparently, Pytest is not really fond of "multiple yields" in a fixture and returns a `yield_fixture function has more than one 'yield'` error

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: E.g. change the function to `def test_urls(e): assert get(e).status_code < 400`, decorate with `@pytest.mark.parametrize('e', ['e_1', 'e_2', ..., 'e_n'])`

Comment: @hoefling that seems very nice! I'll give it a try tomorrow, but seems really promising. Thank you

Comment: @hoefling it worked perfectly, thank you! If you provide an answer bellow, I'll accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the example in [Parametrizing fixtures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html), you can implement the test as:

```
import pytest

endpoints = ['e_1', 'e_2', ..., 'e_n']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('endpoint', endpoints)
def test_urls(endpoint):
    r = get(endpoint)
    assert r.status_code < 400
```

This will run `test_urls` `n` times, once per endpoint:

```
test_spam::test_urls[e_1] PASSED
test_spam::test_urls[e_2] PASSED
...
test_spam::test_urls[e_n] PASSED
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: The url of the to mentioned reference has changed. Here is the correct url (accessible at the time of this comment) https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html. editing the answer was not possible because thee edit queue is full.